# How to avoid adding renditions for pdf uploading into DAM?

Tags: java, pdf, assets, aem, dam

When I upload pdf file to cq5 I see following structure in my crx:

[image]

This structure looks strange for me. I don't understand why do I see png renditions here.
How can I use these renditions?

My current vision that these renditions couldn't be helpful. Thus I want to achieve that after uploading PDF files into DAM these renditions doesn't generate.

Can you provide steps for this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

after my changes in workflow:
[image]

before my changes:

[image]

### update 2

I set dimensions follows:
[image]

but I see old result after pdf and jpg uploading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of these renditions is, as per their name, that they can be used to display thumbnails of the documents — e.g. you may want to display the front cover of each PDF if in a gallery section.

The thumbnail is created by the "DAM Update Asset" workflow (http://www.example.com/etc/workflow/models/dam/update_asset.html; until v5.6) in its **Thumbnail creation** step — I'm not sure that you can configure this to skip certain file types.

To get around this, you could remove this step and replace it with an **Create Web Enabled Image** step — this will allow you to specify MIME-types to skip over in its arguments panel:

[image]

Alternatively, you could [write a bespoke Process class](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/WorkflowPrecessStep.html) which would use ImageMagick to generate thumbnails but ignoring PDFs.

Comment: at this link http://www.example.com/etc/workflow/models/dam/update_asset.html I see following information: 
*Example Domain

This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.

More information...*

Comment: And one more question: we have a lot of environments. I cannot access to each environment and change step using user interface. Can I achive it by code manipulation?

Comment: Just replace example.com with the address of your box, e.g. `http://localhost:4502`. To move workflows between environments, you could make them part of a CRX package - either through the package manager or by exporting with VLT and adding to your version controlled code. They're stored in the JCR under `/etc/workflow/models`.

Comment: I steps according your manual but anuway I see renditions for pdf. Please read update

Comment: @gstackoverflow Could you cross-check that the mime-type of the file you're uploading *is* `application/pdf` & see if the process is logging out anything when the file is uploaded?

Comment: I forgot to click save workflow.  Now I have another result.  But problem that for jpg and for pdf I see same result without renditions. I want to see different behaviour for pdf and jpg. How can I check uploaded myme-type?

Comment: 1-dc:format
String
application/pdf  2-dc:format
String
image/jpeg

Comment: @gstackoverflow It may be because you haven't specified a width/height for the rendition you want — are you seeing any output in the logs?

Comment: Tomorrow I will see logs. Maybe it would helpful. About specify dimensions. At this menu I can specify only one set of dimension(one width one height). All another mime-types should work under the old. In old version I set 3 different dimensions and as you can see I got 3 pictures with different resolutions.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I try one more time and I got a success in general.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yeah, I think this process step will just create a single rendition, but you can add as many of these steps as required. Glad you got it sorted :)